# SSL Termination with Comodo and how to use Cloudflare services at the same time

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

My website is managed by [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), basically, the direct IP access is disabled. And also, I have a [Comodo SSL certificate](https://ssl.comodo.com/comodo-ssl-certificate.php?track=8172) purchased from Comodo as well.

As per [this](https://www.siteground.com/kb/using-cloudflare-shows-comodo-ssl-instead-one-server/), I believe installing the Comodo certificate purchased by me on the server instead of Cloudflare and using Cloudflare services (Direct Ip blocking) is impossible.

Is it true?

I have configured all the SSL configurations (Comodo SSL Certificate) in server level. Now the problem is with Cloudflare and server.

How can I use both Cloudflare and the server level SSL termination?

Please help me out!
Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.